# union 3 table and then i want to display null values as 'X'

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, isnull

i have 3 table that union, this is the sql code

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(dd, [date]) as Date
FROM edrsDB..tbl_status
WHERE DATEPART(MM, [date]) = 3
And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017
Union 
SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(DD,[date]) as Date
FROM edrsDB..tbl_public_holiday
WHERE DATEPART(MM, [date]) = 3
And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017
Union
SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(DD,[Date]) as Date 
FROM edrsDB..tbl_station_weekend
WHERE DATEPART(MM, [date]) = 3
And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017
And date IS NOT NULL) AS monthlyRpt
PIVOT (MAX(status)
FOR userid IN (XSP, BSR, BPT, XPW, IPH, XTH, TGG, XKG, XKM, XLG, KBR, KUA, LGK,MKZ, PEN, XGM, JHB, XBN, STW, TIN, MUA)) AS pivottable
```

after i run this sql query i got many null... so i want the null value display as 'X'

can anyone suggest something

this is the result

[null result after union](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGDXX.png)

Comment: I think you can wrap this SQL into subquery, and apply isnull() on every column in the outer query.

Comment: @BSamedi can you show how?

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
select
    Date,
    isnull(XSP, 'X') as XSP,
    isnull(BSR, 'X') as BSR,
    isnull(BPT, 'X') as BPT,
    isnull(XPW, 'X') as XPW,
    isnull(IPH, 'X') as IPH,
    isnull(XTH, 'X') as XTH,
    isnull(TGG, 'X') as TGG,
    isnull(XKG, 'X') as XKG,
    isnull(XKM, 'X') as XKM,
    isnull(XLG, 'X') as XLG,
    isnull(KBR, 'X') as KBR,
    isnull(KUA, 'X') as KUA,
    isnull(LGK, 'X') as LGK,
    isnull(MKZ, 'X') as MKZ,
    isnull(PEN, 'X') as PEN,
    isnull(XGM, 'X') as XGM,
    isnull(JHB, 'X') as JHB,
    isnull(XBN, 'X') as XBN,
    isnull(STW, 'X') as STW,
    isnull(TIN, 'X') as TIN,
    isnull(MUA, 'X') as MUA
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(dd, [date]) as Date
    FROM edrsDB..tbl_status
    WHERE DATEPART(MM, [date]) = 3
    And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017
    Union 
    SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(DD,[date]) as Date
    FROM edrsDB..tbl_public_holiday
    WHERE DATEPART(MM, [date]) = 3
    And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017
    Union
    SELECT DISTINCT userid, status , DATEPART(DD,[Date]) as Date 
    FROM edrsDB..tbl_station_weekend
    WHERE DATEPART(MM, [date]) = 3
    And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017
    And date IS NOT NULL
) AS monthlyRpt
PIVOT (MAX(status)
    FOR userid IN (XSP, BSR, BPT, XPW, IPH, XTH, TGG, XKG, XKM, XLG, KBR, KUA, LGK,MKZ, PEN, XGM, JHB, XBN, STW, TIN, MUA)
) AS pivottable
```

Comment: You are welcome! Could you please mark the answer "Correct" ?

Comment: i cant mark as correct.,  my reputation to low to mark that answer

Comment: Here is how you can mark the question accepted [https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)